# Windows 7 Admin Corrupted, Cannot Run CMD as Admin, and Cannot Start in Safe Mode

Tags: windows-7, administrator, user-profiles

Windows 7 Admin Corrupted, Cannot Run CMD as Admin, and Cannot Start in Safe Mode.

That about sums it up.  Please help.  Only one other standar profile on the machine. No apparent reason for the corruption.

Cheers.

Comment: Can you get this tool to run  http://www.tweaking.com/content/page/windows_repair_all_in_one.html   It can repair "Safe Mode" and dozens of other things.

Comment: [See this answer](http://superuser.com/questions/72244/what-can-i-do-if-i-forgot-my-windows-password/247953#247953) if you use the "alternate method" mentioned in that answer then [use the new user command given in this answer to add a new admin account](http://superuser.com/a/515182/40928)

Answer (score 1):

Try creating another administrator account using Hiren's Boot CD.

1. [Download Hiren's Boot CD](http://www.hirensbootcd.org/download/)
2. Write it to a USB or CD from another computer
3. Boot to it on the computer which has problema
4. Choose the Mini Windows XP option
5. In the menu, under password recovery, choose NT Password Recovery
6. Choose the option to create an admin account.

Comment: Where to get Hirens boot cd  . ;-)

Comment: @Moab http://www.hirensbootcd.org/download/