# Hide "Input method" widget from taskbar

Tags: windows, keyboard, windows-11, language, input-languages

I recently changed Windows language from English (US) to English (UK).

I decided to keep using the English (US) keyboard. But now, I see this input method in the taskbar constantly. How do I hide it? I don't remember adding an English (UK) keyboard anywhere.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question although it's from Windows 10? https://superuser.com/questions/1103532/how-to-hide-the-eng-language-icon-in-notification-area-windows-10