# My only local Administrator login account vanished after changing PW

Tags: windows-server-2008

I am new to server administering and learning and I have an old dell server with windows server 2008 standard installed.  I almost forgot the password for the admininstrator account so I went in and changed it from the control panel user section.  Now after reboot the administrator button vanished.  It was the only administrator account.  What happened and how do I log in as admin now?  Ive looked and cannot see anybody with this same issue on searching.  I logged on to a normal user account and looked at properties of the user groups and I see the Adminstrator account there and it doesnt say its disabled.  It just doesnt want to show on login screen for some reason.

Comment: You will need to boot to an installation disk, enable the built-in Administrator account, in order to further diagnose your problem

Comment: Thank you Tamhound. I will get the disk and try to get the details.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the issue by creating a usb boot disk.  Then in recovery console I forced the cmd prompt to open where I replaced an utilman.exe to cmd.exe superbly explained here: 
http://www.top-password.com/blog/4-ways-to-enable-built-in-administrator-account-on-windows/ 
Then i tried activating the administrator by using 
net user administrator /active:yes
that didnt fix my issue.  So i found another link that showed me how to create an entirely new user and assign it to administrators group shown here: 
[Create admin user from command line](https://superuser.com/questions/515175/create-admin-user-from-command-line).

Thank you Ramhound for starting me at the right direction.